# Where can I find an .xsd file to provide intellisense for Castle Windsor?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I'm looking for an .xsd schema file to drop into my Visual Studio directory to provide intellisense for the xml configuration file for the Castle Windsor IoC container. I've looked in the downloaded code for Windsor, as well as googled several different ways. I see many people asking the same question, but no answers. Anyone know if there is such a document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

http://jimblogdog.blogspot.com/2008/05/castlewindsor-schema-enables-visual.html

Here is the link to download the castle windsor schema:

http://www.projectdistributor.net/Releases/Release.aspx?releaseId=427

Good Luck!

Comment: the schema link is currently down

Answer (score 3):

I have rehosted the project-distributor schema zip on google code [here](http://code.google.com/p/castlewindsorschema/). The zip contains schema, example usage and a readme to install it.